# can someone help me about javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="toggler" class="toggler"> 
    <div id="toggler" class="line1"></div> 
    <div id="toggler" class="line2"></div> 
    <div id="toggler" class="line3"></div>
```

```
function toggled(){
document.getElementById('toggler').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("toggled").style.display = 'block';
});
}
toggled()
```

Why is this Code Not Working i want it to toggle navbar number 2 in mobile

Comment: yes it is html code:

        <div id="toggler" class="toggler">
            <div id="toggler" class="line1"></div>
            <div id="toggler" class="line2"></div>
            <div id="toggler" class="line3"></div>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="toggled">
            
    </div>

toggled clas its with css and display none;

Comment: Your code is a one-off, it makes the job only once, there's nothing which would check the state and then toggle it.

Comment: its not toggling it thats the problme

Comment: maybe because you need to use class, toogler must be unique because is a ID

Comment: You can [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519) to toggle almost anything.

Comment: You're reusing the same ID "toggler"; IDs must be unique. You're making no attempt to "toggle" anything (you just set the display to 'block'). And the element you're changing doesn't exist (there is no element with ID "toggled".)

Answer (score -1):

## how to add the toggle function!

we can use two classes with CSS Styles:

1. `.visible`
2. `.invisible`

`.invisible` has inside `display:none;` so and is **used** as the **default** in `.toogled`

and the `.visible` is NOT used as default

```css
display: block !important;

/* important because we can override the .invisible class */
```

but using Javascript (CLASSLIST), we can write

```js
/* here the magic */

toogled.classList.toggle('visible');
```

> `.classList.toggle();` **check** if there is the class there is or not,

> if there is: REMOVE the class

> if there isn't: ADD the class!

so if we nested the code above in a CLICK listener,

the first time set to visible,

then set to invisible,

another time you will click it will be visible! (this loop don't stop)

### some mini problems there

##### same name in IDs of elements

the first problem is you have the same name of ID in most of the elements.

> an ID needs to be **unique!**

if you really want to use the same name for more elements... **use** instead of **classes**

##### childs of `.toogler` parent class.

if you want to get all the children, you **don't need** to write the class for **every `div`** you have

just **one time in the parent** and your job is done!

```html
<div class="toggler">

    ...

</div>
```

yes, now with JavaScript you can use this for selecting the parent class:

```js
let toogler = document.querySelector('.toggler');
```

---

... I think is better to see now the code for understand

## the code

```js
let toogler = document.querySelector('.toggler');
let toogled = document.querySelector('.toggled');

function toggled() {
  toogler.addEventListener('click', function() {
    toogled.classList.toggle('visible');
    console.log('clicked');
  });
}
toggled();
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="toggler">
      <div class="line1">CLICK ME PLEASE 1</div>
      <div class="line2">CLICK ME PLEASE 2</div>
      <div class="line3">CLICK ME PLEASE 3</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="toggled invisible">toogled</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thx bro it works