# If "THIS" + "THIS" clicked, do this (in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I wanna do a simple thing but i do not find the correct way to do it like u saw in the title.
I have some buttons which are selectionnable, i just wanna say that if one of them+ another one is selected, we cant select another one (or 2).
Theorically it's really simple i think, but i wanted to have some ideas instead of doing something useless which is half working.

[image]

I'll try to schematize :
All theses squares are divs with text in and style.
When you click on them, (that's what i called "selected") they're switching color.

So for example i want that if we click on "1" + "2" : we can click only on "A" + "C" OR "A" + "D". (Not A+B).

That's the only thing i wanted to understand.
I hope that you'll understand.

Thanks a lot,
Cordially
Zartex

Comment: What elements exactly are these? A button cannot be “selected”, so is it `<input type="radio">`? How are you checking selectedness? You aren’t actually redeclaring all your variables, are you? Having so many variables and so many IDs is definitely not good design. What is the actual logic? If an element from one group is selected, the corresponding element from the other group cannot be selected? What exactly changes from this logic when _two_ elements from the same group are selected? Which elements can be selected in the first place, i.e. what is the set of possible selections?

Comment: This goes wrong from the beginning. IDs are not purposed to identify tabular data, use strict HTML structure, and store the references into a NodeList or array by retrieving the elements with document/element.querySelectorAll.

Comment: I was reconsidering my questioin and yeah it's not really clear. When i said select buttons, in my website it's about the color changing only on the click. How can I do all my codes without a lot of variable and ids if i need them because i have a lot of buttons/slots etc?

Comment: Please post the related markup too, then we can see what we can do.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events).

Comment: By the way, this is not my real code, i mean, i dont have one because i was just asking theorically how can i do "that". But i couldnt ask my question on this forum if i didnt add some code. I have some divs with text etc which are changing color on click, and i want to let one disapear or unselectable if i already clicked on 2 of them. I dont rly know how to explain it

Comment: OK, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519), it's a generic class toggler, with which you can toggle almost anything. You can add an "beforetoggle event listener" to the code, which detects when two elements have been selected.

Comment: Thanks, i update my question with a schema, that might be easier to understand. Tell me :)