# Why is this.id not working in my switch...case?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, this

The code should show the plot for the book cover you click on whilst changing the background to an alternative cover of the book, but it isn't doing anything. I have some backup code that works, but I liked this solution more.

My js code:

```
function mostraTrama(){
    try{
        switch(this.id){
            case "TramaVdR":
                nodoTramaVdR.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaScelta");
                nodoTramaPdL.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                nodoTramaG.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/way_of_kings_bg.jpg')";
                break
            case "TramaPdL":
                nodoTramaVdR.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                nodoTramaPdL.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaScelta");
                nodoTramaG.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/words_of_radiance_bg.jpg')";
                break
            case "TramaG":
                nodoTramaVdR.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                nodoTramaPdL.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaNonScelta");
                nodoTramaG.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaScelta");
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/oathbringer_bg.jpg')";
                break
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        alert("mostraTrama " + e);
    }
}

function gestoreLoadRomanzi(){
    try {
        nodoTramaViaDeiRe = document.getElementById("TramaViaDeiRe");
        nodoTramaParoleDiLuce = document.getElementById("TramaParoleDiLuce");
        nodoTramaGiuramento = document.getElementById("TramaGiuramento");
        nodoTramaVdR = document.getElementById("TramaVdR");
        nodoTramaPdL = document.getElementById("TramaPdL");
        nodoTramaG = document.getElementById("TramaG");
        nodoTramaViaDeiRe.onclick = mostraTrama;
        nodoTramaParoleDiLuce.onclick = mostraTrama;
        nodoTramaGiuramento.onclick = mostraTrama;
    } catch ( e ) {
        alert("gestoreLoadRomanzi " + e);
    }
}
```

All three start off with class = "TramaNonScelta", which has display: none, and when clicked they should change to class = "TramaScelta", which has display: inline. The IDs all match to the ones they have in the HTML document.

My alternate functioning way is to have a separate function for each book instead of a single one for all of them.

EDIT: I also have a very similar code for another program that instead of using .setAttribute uses .innerHTML and works without any problems (but my professor doesn't want us to use .innerHTML in this project)

Comment: Usually something happens, have you took a look at the console, there might be error messages? Also, when you're getting more books, this code will be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: `.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaScelta")` makes no sense. Look at the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) again. Use [`classList`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead.

Comment: What's the error? Also, share how are you invoking those functions because that determines what value 'this' will refer to.

Comment: `nodoTramaVdR.setAttribute = ("class", "TramaScelta");` => `nodoTramaVdR.setAttribute("class", "TramaScelta");` - notwithstanding the nightmare of maintaining this code

Comment: @Teemu The console is telling me nothing. As for the more books problem, it's for a university project and the page will only have the three books on it fortunately.

Comment: The console is telling you nothing because javascript does not stop you re-assigning a function.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a lesson for your future work, where there will be more books ... Drop the `try ... catch`es, they're just preventing you to see what really is going on in your code, and it's much more convenient to read a full error message (including the call stack) from the console.

Comment: You can use `event.currentTarget.id` instead than `this.id` and `function mostraTrama(event)`   but it would need report the console error to understand the problem.   Furthermore use classname property instead than setAttribute,  or classList.add

Comment: @r.kinder Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519). It contains a parametrizable reusable generic class toggler. As it is, it doesn't resolve the individual image sources, but it's easy to create a data object mapping the `src`s to the elements, and then change the background based on that data.