# How do you save a function to call on it later to be executed when a certain promise is fullfilled example beneath

Tags: javascript

Found solution: I managed to create a function that i then call, i did.

```
export function Checkoutsystem_Close() {
$w("#Address2").hide("fade");
$w("#Line4").hide("fade");
$w("#PostalCode").hide("fade");
$w("#Line5").hide("fade");
$w("#Name").hide("fade");
}

export function StopLineTop_viewportEnter(event) 
{Checkoutsystem_Close()}
export function StopLineBottom_viewportEnter(event) 
{Checkoutsystem_Close()}
export function CloseButtonHitbox_click(event) 
{Checkoutsystem_Close()}     
export function Glass_click(event) {Checkoutsystem_Close()}
```

Started coding yesterday and all i know how to use is hide and show functions but so far ive managed to build a very pretty checkout system. On my basic knowledge. But its so many elements to show and hide so I would like to learn how to save a function so the code becomes very short effective simple and light.

---

Id like to save this whole part of code beneath to be saved, so I can just call on it later so something like;

---

export function StopLineBottom_viewportEnter(event) {    "function close checkout" }

---

### The code I would like to save and recall later:

```
export function StopLineBottom_viewportEnter(event) {    

$w("#Glass").hide("");    
$w("#CheckoutBox1").hide("");   
$w("#Galasky").hide("");
$w("#PreviewBox").hide("");
$w("#GalaskyStarlight").hide("");
$w("#ProductPreview").hide("");
$w("#Price").hide("");
$w("#Address1").hide("");
$w("#Line1").hide("");
$w("#Country").hide("");
$w("#Line2").hide("");
$w("#City").hide("");
$w("#Line3").hide("");
$w("#Address2").hide("");
$w("#Line4").hide("");
$w("#PostalCode").hide("");
$w("#Line5").hide("");
$w("#Name").hide("");
$w("#Line6").hide("");
$w("#Number").hide("")
$w("#Line7").hide("");
$w("#CheckoutButton").hide("");
$w("#CheckoutBox2").hide("");
$w("#PaymentProviders").hide("");
$w("#CloseButtonIcon").hide("");
$w("#CloseButtonHitbox").hide("");
}
```

Comment: Whenever you find yourself indexing `id`s or variables, you know you're doing it wrong. Use arrays instead of indexed variables and classes instead of indexed `id`s. Maybe you could apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519) ..?

Comment: Also please show enough code for us to understand what you are doing. What is $w and why are you passing an empty string to the .hide("") ? And why not wrap the stuff you want to hide in a container and hide that?

Comment: I am coding a wix website

Comment: As @Teemu said your best bet is to look into classes or into hiding the whole checkout as one container.

Comment: Wix or Velo site?

Comment: wix site (dev mode) but i figured out how to do it some guys on reddit came to the rescue, thx btw <3

Comment: What do you mean by "*when a certain promise is fullfilled*"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*how to save a function*". A function already *is* stored in a variable, and can be called at any time - now or later - as often as you want to.