# Trigger DIV content on button click + change button text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to trigger the visibility of a DIV via a button.

My code looks like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
var moreText = document.getElementById("csrmore");
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  let ishidden = x.classList.contains("hidden")
if (ishidden == true) {
x.classList.remove("hidden");
x.classList.add("shown");
moreText.innerHTML = "Show less";
}
else  {
x.classList.remove("shown");
x.classList.add("hidden");
moreText.innerHTML = "Show more";
}   
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  display:none
}

.shown {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<button id="csrmore" onclick="myFunction()">
Show more
</button>


<div id="myDIV" class="hidden">
This is the triggerable content.
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zxa0Lg2/

It works fine, however since I am a JS starter, I was wondering if this is bad practice or is it a totally fine piece of code?

Thanks for every help :)

Comment: You could make the code reusable, then you never need to write it again. Also, I'd prefer storing the state in a JS variable, retrieving the DOM is slow.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the "retrieving the DOM is slow" part a little further?

Comment: DOM is a huge object, and retrieving a value from it it takes much more time than retrieving a JS variable. Not that it would have any meaning on this particular case, but in general, it's better to manage JS variables with JS, and access DOM only when it's really necessary. See an example of a reusable and parametrizable [toggle function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to go about it. Make it all relative. The button is clicked and the javascript finds the content associated to that button to show/hide. This way you don't need any ID tags and you can have as many show/hide buttons as you want on the page.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // after the page loads...
  document.querySelectorAll('.csrmore').forEach(button => {
    // find all the 'show more' buttons and for each one...
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // when someone clicks this button
      let content = e.target.closest('.container').querySelector('.content');
      // find the content div associated with this button
      content.classList.toggle('hidden');
      // toggle on or off the content
      e.target.innerText = content.classList.contains('hidden') ? 'Show more' : 'Hide';
      // change the text of the button
    })

  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button class="csrmore">
Show more
</button>
  <div class="content hidden">
    This is the triggerable content.
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class='container'>
  <button class="csrmore">
Show more
</button>
  <div class="content hidden">
    This is the triggerable content.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine way to do this! This is not the solution I would not have come up with, but it is actually pretty clever. I would have thought to have done it by toggling TARGET.style.visibility to either "hidden" or "visible" when clicking the button. Again though, your code looks perfectly fine!