# Show content when a button is pressed and change colour the active button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to show a content when a button is pressed and change colour of the active button. Currently I'm able to perform both the operation individually, but I don't get how to merge these functionalities.

To show the content, my script looks like :

```js
function changedata(parameter){
  if(parameter==0){
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'flex';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mydata{
  display:none;
  font-size: 25;
}
.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(80vh - 100px);
  background: rgb(133, 43, 43);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.chartBox {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 1px 22px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
  background: white;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color: #005201;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 250);;
}
.button {
  background-color: rgb(69, 9, 188);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">Myreport</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">Mydata</button>
<div id="mydata">
  <h1>This is my Data</h1>
</div>
  <div class="chartCard" id="myreport">
    <div class="chartBox">
      <p>Ram</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartBox">
      <p>Shyam</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to highlight the active button so i added `.highlight{background-color: green;}` in css and a new script as :

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (button in buttons) {
  buttons[button].onclick = function() {
    console.log('test')
    buttons.forEach(function(btn){
      btn.classList.remove('highlight');
    })
    this.classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
```

```js
function changedata(parameter){
  if(parameter==0){
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'flex';
  }
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (button in buttons) {
  buttons[button].onclick = function() {
    console.log('test')
    buttons.forEach(function(btn){
      btn.classList.remove('highlight');
    })
    this.classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mydata{
  display:none;
  font-size: 25;
}
.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(90vh - 100px);
  background: rgb(133, 43, 43);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.chartBox {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 1px 22px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
  background: white;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color: #005201;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 250);;
}
.button {
  background-color: rgb(69, 9, 188);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">Myreport</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">Mydata</button>
<div id="mydata">
  <h1>This is my Data</h1>
</div>
<div class="chartCard" id="myreport">
  <div class="chartBox">
    <p>Ram</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chartBox">
    <p>Shyam</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to achieve both the functionality together ? kindly looking for help.

Comment: Strip the `id`s from the elements, `id` is not suitable identifier for this purpose, use a class instead. Also, don't iterate through the elements to get the current active element, store a reference to that element instead.

Comment: @Teemu may you please add it as code snippets in answer it will help me to learn more. I'm an absolute beginer in web dev

Comment: Please take a look at [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the class in `changedata()` and add it to the clicked element.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('highlight');
});
event.target.classList.add('highlight');
```

```js
function changedata(parameter){
  document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('highlight');
  });
  event.target.classList.add('highlight');
  if(parameter==0){
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'flex';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#mydata{
  display:none;
  font-size: 25;
}
.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(90vh - 100px);
  background: rgb(133, 43, 43);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.chartBox {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 1px 22px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
  background: white;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color: #005201;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 250);;
}
.button {
  background-color: rgb(69, 9, 188);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="button highlight" onclick="changedata(1)">Myreport</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">Mydata</button>
<div id="mydata">
  <h1>This is my Data</h1>
</div>
<div class="chartCard" id="myreport">
  <div class="chartBox">
  <p>Ram</p>
</div>
<div class="chartBox">
  <p>Shyam</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't get it sir, may you please add it in code snippets

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had a query, for the first time we can see Myreport already on screen, so by default i want to make this button (Myeport) colour green, but when Mydata button is clicked it turns green, that time i want Myreport button to go back blue , can we do this. and again when my report is clicked it becomes green.

Comment: @GouravkrSingh Just add `highlight` to the MyReport button, I edited so you can see

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.onclick` on the buttons twice. By doing this the first function will be overwritten by second function. Solution to that is `addEventListener()` method. Which attaches an specific event handler to an element. You can also add more than one handler for an event if you use this method.

Keeping functions separate is considered as good practice in JS. In snippet below there is a function named `setActiveClass()`. There are two parameters first is **element** and second one is for element's **classname**. If you want to change the classname you just have to change the value of variable `activeClassName` rather changing it everywhere.

```js
let myReportBtn = document.getElementById("reportBtn");
let myDataBtn = document.getElementById("dataBtn");

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function changedata(bool) {
  let myReport = document.getElementById('myreport');
  let myData = document.getElementById('mydata');
  
  const activeClassName = 'highlight';
  
  if (!bool) {
    myReport.style.display = 'none';
    myData.style.display = 'block';
    setActiveClass(myDataBtn, activeClassName);
  } else {
    myData.style.display = 'none';
    myReport.style.display = 'flex';
    setActiveClass(myReportBtn, activeClassName);
  }
}

function setActiveClass(elem, classname){
  buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.classList.remove(`${classname}`);
  });
  elem.classList.add(`${classname}`);
}

myReportBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  changedata(true);
});

myDataBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  changedata(false);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mydata {
  display: none;
  font-size: 25;
}

.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(50vh - 100px);
  background: rgb(133, 43, 43);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chartBox {
  width: 650px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 1px 22px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
  background: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #005201;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 250);
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(69, 9, 188);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button" id="reportBtn">Myreport</button>
  <button class="button" id="dataBtn">Mydata</button>
  <div id="mydata">
    <h1>This is my Data</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="chartCard" id="myreport">
    <div class="chartBox">
      <p>Ram</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartBox">
      <p>Shyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```