# Toggle read more button in an array for each element

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, toggle

I have an array with this data:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id:1,
    img:'img url',
    title: 'title text',
    description: 'some text'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    img:'img url',
    title: 'title text',
    description: 'some text'
  },
  {
    id:3,
    img:'img url',
    title: 'title text',
    description: 'some text'
  }
]
```

A div that I create for each element in that array:

```
    <div class="big_container">
       <div class="image_container">
          <img src=""/>
       </div>
       <div class="description_container">
           <h4>></h4>
           <p class="text">${item.description}</p>
           <button id="${item.id} class="read-more-btn">Read more</button> 
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to create a "Read more" button under description that will toggle between hide/show.

I tested like this. I am adding an event listener to each button. :

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.read-more-btn')
for (i of btns) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const container = document.querySelectorAll('.description_container')
    container.forEach((i, index) => console.log(i))
  });
}
```

Here is CSS:

/* read more */

```
.read-more-btn::before {
    content: 'read more';
}

.description_container.active  .read-more-btn::before {
    content:'show less'
}

.description_container.active p {
    display: block;

}
```

The problem I have, when I click on one of the buttons I toggle all of them. How can i solve that?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271006/1169519), it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `querySelectorAll()` from the document, which retrieve all the `.description_container` elements in the DOM.

To find the ones related to the clicked button you can use the `target` property of the event passed to the handler function, then `closest()` to get the nearest common container before finally calling `querySelector()`.

Here's a working example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.read-more-btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const text = e.target.closest('.description_container').querySelector('.text');
    console.log(text.textContent);
  });
});
```

```css
.read-more-btn::before {
  content: 'read more';
}

.description_container.active .read-more-btn::before {
  content: 'show less'
}

.description_container.active p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="big_container">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="description_container">
    <h4></h4>
    <p class="text">item.description_1</p>
    <button class="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="big_container">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="description_container">
    <h4></h4>
    <p class="text">item.description_2</p>
    <button class="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="big_container">
  <div class="image_container">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="description_container">
    <h4></h4>
    <p class="text">item.description_2</p>
    <button class="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```